# Laravel: listening AMQP queue

Tags: php, laravel, rabbitmq, listener, amqp

How do I implement a listening queue in laravel?
I'm using [AMQP library](https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib)

In RabbitMQ documentation this looks like that:

```
$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
$channel = $connection->channel();

$channel->queue_declare('hello', false, false, false, false);

$callback = function($msg) {
  echo " [x] Received ", $msg->body, "\n";
};

$channel->basic_consume('hello', '', false, true, false, false, $callback);

while(count($channel->callbacks)) {
    $channel->wait();
}
```

*p.s. Sorry for my English :|*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest installing AMQP Laravel driver. There are some:

- https://github.com/vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq
- https://github.com/php-enqueue/laravel-queue

It would do everything under the hood.